# Equal width and height cell in react-bootstrap Grid

Tags: reactjs, grid, flexbox, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I'm trying to make the `div` cells in `react-bootstrap` Grid have **automatically equal width and height**. The **content size of these cells will vary** and so will the **width of the entire grid**. The goal is to make it responsive and independent of the size of the cell contents.

Also, I am thinking about using something modern like FlexBox layout for React to achieve this (if it exists). I used FlexBox before and I know it's probably the best for achieving layouts like this.

```
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

...

<Grid fluid={true}>
    <Row className="show-grid" style={{border: "1px solid brown"}}>
        {dummyData.map(function(object, i){
            return <Col key={i} sm={6} md={3} style={{border: "1px solid yellow"}}>
                <div style={{width:"100%", height:"100%, border: "1px solid blue", backgroundImage:"url("+dummyData[i].url+")"}}>{dummyData[i].city}</div>
            </Col>;
        })}
    </Row>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use a React component that sets height to width passed as a prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import Dimensions from 'react-dimensions';

class Square extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    width:this.props.containerWidth,
                }}>
                {this.props.city}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dimensions()(Square) // Enhanced component
```

Corresponding changes to the Grid:

```
<Grid fluid={true}>
    <Row className="show-grid" style={{border: "1px solid brown"}}>
        {dummyData.map(function(object, i){
            return <Col key={i} sm={6} md={3} style={{border: "1px solid yellow"}}>
                <Square image={dummyData[i].url} title={dummyData[i].city} value={dummyData[i].value}></Square>
            </Col>;
        })}
    </Row>
</Grid>
```